# Forum Response Error: Duplicate entry for PRIMARY key

Tags: php, mysql

I have been writing some code for a forum and am new to PHP, but I have run into some trouble.
When I test the program by entering an answer, I get a web page that says "ERROR".

After changing `echo "ERROR"` to `echo mysql_error()`, the webpage changed to this:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp5\htdocs\add_answer.php on line 14
>
> Notice: Undefined index: a_name in C:\xampp5\htdocs\add_answer.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined index: a_email in C:\xampp5\htdocs\add_answer.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined index: a_answer in C:\xampp5\htdocs\add_answer.php on line 32
>   Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="forum_answer"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get value of id that sent from hidden field 
$id = $_POST['id'];

// Find highest answer number. 
$sql="SELECT MAX(a_id) AS Maxa_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE question_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// add + 1 to highest answer number and keep it in variable name "$Max_id". if there no answer yet set it = 1 
if ($rows) {
    $Max_id = $rows['Maxa_id']+1;
}
else {
    $Max_id = 1;
}

// get values that sent from form 
$a_name = $_POST['a_name'];
$a_email = $_POST['a_email'];
$a_answer = $_POST['a_answer']; 

$datetime=date("d/m/y H:i:s"); // create date and time

// Insert answer 
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(question_id, a_id, a_name, a_email, a_answer, a_datetime)VALUES('$id', '$Max_id', '$a_name', '$a_email', '$a_answer', '$datetime')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

if($result2){
    echo "Successful<BR>";
    echo "<a href='view_topic.php?id=".$id."'>View your answer</a>";

    // If added new answer, add value +1 in reply column 
    $tbl_name2="forum_question";
    $sql3="UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

// Close connection
mysql_close

();
?>
```

For the moment I am not concerned with security, as I intend to fix security issues later down the track.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Print out the proper error message instead of the useless error.

Comment: Replace `echo "ERROR"` with `echo mysql_error()` and edit the result into your question.

Comment: As someone commented above, do not use mysql_query. If you are new to PHP use the PDO library instead, or if you less adventourous use the MySQLi library.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition in your code. When multiple users hit the database at the same time, they *will* eventually read the same `$Max_id` and subsequently try to insert the same `$Max_id + 1`. Eg.:

1. User 1 selects id 42
2. User 2 selects id 42
3. User 1 inserts id 43
4. User 2 inserts id 43

You need to declare the primary key column with the [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute (or simply declare it as a [`SERIAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)). This way, the database engine will automatically update the id with a guaranteed unique value when you insert new rows.